# Delegate function really needed while loop(Voting example)?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, voting

I'm learning Solidity, and referring given example of [Voting in a doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/solidity-by-example.html#voting).
But I'm not able to understand one thing about `delegate` function. 
Here is the Delegate method:

```
/// Delegate your vote to the voter `to`.
function delegate(address to) public {
    // assigns reference
    Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
    require(!sender.voted, "You already voted.");

    require(to != msg.sender, "Self-delegation is disallowed.");

    // Forward the delegation as long as
    // `to` also delegated.
    // In general, such loops are very dangerous,
    // because if they run too long, they might
    // need more gas than is available in a block.
    // In this case, the delegation will not be executed,
    // but in other situations, such loops might
    // cause a contract to get "stuck" completely.
    while (voters[to].delegate != address(0)) {
        to = voters[to].delegate;

        // We found a loop in the delegation, not allowed.
        require(to != msg.sender, "Found loop in delegation.");
    }
}
```

What is use of while loop here? they already checked with self delegation with

```
require(to != msg.sender, "Self-delegation is disallowed.");
```

And we can check initial address condition with `if` condition.

```
  if (voters[to].delegate != address(0)) {
            to = voters[to].delegate;
  ...
  ...
```

What is special about While loop here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop is for checking that no delegation loop exists like this:

`voter A === delegate ===> voter B === delegate ===> ... === delegate ===> voter A`

Whereas the line `require(to != msg.sender, "Self-delegation is disallowed.");` only checks for a direct self-delegate:

`voter A === delegate ===> voter A`